# sorting on date in angular 5 with values more than 10

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
this.data = this.data.sort((a, b) => 
new Date(a.JsonDate).getTime() - new Date(b.JsonDate).getTime()).reverse();
```

I am working on Date sort with more than 10 values, its working fine for values till 9.
It's breaking for values greater than 10, kindly help me how can I make it work for greater than 10, I tried using `>` sign but it's not working as expected.

```
this.data = this.data.sort((a, b) => 
new Date(a.JsonDate).getTime() > new Date(b.JsonDate).getTime()).reverse();
```

Comment: When you say it's not working, can you be more specific? What happens? Also, it would be great if you could create a Stackblitz that reproduces the issue

Comment: data = [6/20/18,7/20/18,7/20/18,8/20/18,7/20/18,7/22/18,7/20/18,7/20/18,7/25/18,7/20/18,7/20/18,7/20/18,8/27/18,7/22/18,7/20/18,7/20/18,7/20/18,12/19/18,7/20/18,7/10/17] , Its in MM/dd/yy format----> the result is wrong the first value and the sixth is not as per expectation while , if the data is less than 10 values its working fine

Comment: First of all, `sort` method of Array mutates original object. So, you don't need to reassign it. Second thing is strings. I've checked your code and it works correctly with subtraction. Maybe, problem is with strings? What do you have in this .JsonDate?